# cakephp getLastInsertId not working

Tags: cakephp

Here I have used cakephp js helper to send data,After insert One data I need this last id for farther work.Here I have tried bellow code in Addcontroller

```
if ($this->Patient->save($this->request->data)) {
                $lastid=$this->Patient->getLastInsertId();
                $patient=$this->Patient->find('all',array(
               'conditions'=>array('Patient.id'=>$lastid ),
               'recursive' => -1
 ));  
 $this->set('patient', $patient);

}
```

In add.ctp I have tried bellow code but I haven't get last id here.

```
<?php foreach ($patient as $patient): ?>
    <?php echo h($patient['Patient']['id']); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
if ($this->Patient->save($this->request->data)) {
    $id = $this->Patient->id;
    $patient=$this->Patient->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Patient.id'=>$id),'recursive' => -1));

$this->set->('patient', $patient);
//If you are saving the record with ajax which it looks like you 
//might be from your question you will need the following instead
//of $this->set->('patient', $patient); try:

return json_encode($patient);
```

You will then also need to update your js ajax call, you will have a json array to decode so parse it with jquery and append it back into your view.

Cake will always give you the id of record you have just saved, by simply adding $id = $this->MyModel->id; You can  use the id to query for the record.

Answer (score 2):

Method `getLastInsertId()` return id of just saved records.

If you need this id in your view just after save, you must first set that variable in your controller like `$this->set(compact('lastid','patient');`  and then use in view `<?php echo $lastid; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

1. In controller:

   ```
    $lastid=$this->Patient->getLastInsertId();

    $this->set(compact('lastid','patient');
   ```

   Then use `$lastid` in View file.
2. In controller:

   ```
    $lastid=$this->Patient->getLastInsertId();
    $patient['Patient']['last_id'] = $lastid;
   ```

   then use `$patient['Patient']['last_id']` in your view file.